# Swapping Variables by pattern matching?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

Assume you have 2 Integer Variables a and b
How would you swap them only if a > b by using a match expression?
If a <= b do not swap the ints.

In an imperative language:

```
if (a > b){
   int temp=a;
   a=b;
   b=temp;
}
```

Doing the same in ocaml seems surprisingly hard.

I tried

```
let swap a b = 
 match a,b with 
  | a,b when a > b -> b,a
  | a,b when a <= b -> a,b
```

I am trying to do this because in the following function call, I want to make sure that x is the bigger of the two variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without state, you cannot "swap" the values of the variables since the variables are immutable. Your best bet is to use a tuple and introduce new variables in the scope. Example:

```
let diff a b =
    let (min, max) = if a <= b then (a, b) else (b, a)
    in max - min
```

You can of course use the same identifiers and shadow the original variables:

```
let diff a b =
    let (a, b) = if a <= b then (a, b) else (b, a)
    in b - a
```

It doesn't really help with readability though.

Answer (score 3):

One easy way :

```
 let swap a b = 
     if (a>b) then (b,a) 
     else (a,b)
```

But this is not equivalent to the C code, your C code is swapping the value of the variable - this is how imperative language are doing.

In Ocaml, there is no side-effect (except if you use reference to some `int`). This `swap` function will return a tuple whose members are always ordered (the first member will be always smaller than the second order).

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, if you'd like to swap the values in two refs, it would look like the following:

```
let swap a_ref b_ref =
  let a, b = !a_ref, !b_ref in
  a_ref := b;
  b_ref := a
;;
```

which has the type `val swap : 'a ref -> 'a ref -> unit`.